# Using ModRewrite to direct subdomains appropriately fails on MediaTemple

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, lamp, .htaccess

I am familiar with modifying `.htaccess` files but my initial attempts to do so continue to fail.

Ultimately, I want to point users to 'imaginary' subdomains (those which do not exist) so that the subdomain can be parsed correctly with PHP and MySQL to find the particular member's information. It is my assumption that MediaTemple has *something* configured to always check for a true subdomain directory prior to any access so the `.htaccess` file settings are never touched and in turn just generate errors.

For example:

When somebody goes to `www.example.com` currently, it shows the parent site including information on how to become a member. Once a person is a member, their 'unique' URL is:

```
www.example.com?MemberID=12345
```

ultimately, forcing the member to remember the question mark agent equals can be confusing along with the need to remember the proper capitalization and such.

I would 'like' to achieve the following:

```
www.12345.example.com
```

redirects to

```
www.example.com/index.php?MemberID=12345
```

(`index.php` reads the `12345` like a `$_GET` function to properly lookup the `ID`, valid and return response based on that.)

I believe we **could?** achieve the same using information after the slash:

e.g. `www.example.com/12345`

The issue is we already have other pages using `/xxxx` to modify client content as well as I don't want to block anybody's ability to simply visit: `www.example.com/contact` for example as a live link.

(where the site redirects to index, tries to look up memberid = 'contact' and does not find any results).

My .htaccess is currently:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/processing_page.php?ID=%1 [L,R]
```

I would expect based off my needs that typing `www.something.example.com` I would be redirected to: `www.example.com/processing_page.php?something`

Instead, it just redirects to my mediatemple hosting page (essentially stating no subdomain named 'something' exists).

I am running our server on a Media Temple DV 3.5 server running CentOS5 and LAMP stack.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear about your issues. If you are still having issues, I'd recommend contacting our tech support and taking a look at our wiki on specific rules.

If you open up a support request, feel free to contact us through our Twitter or phone support.

Comment: @user59612 - I appreciate the link, however these types of actions are outside of the scope of media temple support as we have already tried that route previously.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com
> RewriteRule .* http://example.com/processing_page.php?ID=%1 [L,R]
> ```
>
> I would expect based off my needs that typing
>   `www.something.example.com` I would be redirected to:
>   `www.example.com/processing_page.php?something`

This code wouldn't actually have done what you required. The first condition specifically excludes any hostname that starts `www.`, so it wouldn't have redirected a request for `www.something.example.com`. You would have had to have requested `something.example.com` for this directive to have stood a chance. Otherwise, you'd just get your default home page.

This is assuming you have a "wildcard" subdomain configured in DNS and an appropriate `ServerAlias` directive defined in the virtual host for your site (and the webserver having been restarted).

To modify the above directives to do what you require, you would have needed something like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([a-z0-9]+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/processing_page.php?ID=%1 [L,R]
```

This should also have gone *before* the first rule that appends the `.php` extension via an internal rewrite. Generally, redirects should always go before rewrites.